# are automated recurring billings really automated?

Tags: e-commerce, recurring-billing

"roll your own recurring billing in your rails app with a cron job, a date field for when they are paid through, and amount each person is paying"

I just saw this entry here in SO and wonder if Automated Recurring Billing is really automated. Do I have to create a script that checks if it is already the right time to bill someone, bill them and then record transactions...or should I let the payment gateway do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the payment gateway you are using and if they support repeat billing. If you need it, then I suggest you find one that does, rather than deal with the issue of storing billing (esp. credit card) details.

Comment: With many payment gateways, you don't have to actually store the credit card number to do recurring billing. You can use a reference transaction to do the recurring billing. You basically tell the payment gateway "bill this customer with the same cc info that was submitted for transaction id 123".

Comment: Ah, it's been a while since I worked with a payment gateway. The theory is still the same though. If the gateway looks after it, it's one less issue I need to worry about coding.